# Не удается передать картинку в QLabel в среде Windows (в Linux работает без проблем)

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel

Не удается вывести картинку в QLabel в среде Windows (в Linux всё работает без проблем).
Пробовал двумя способами. Размер картинки 144х88 пикселей (~ 3 КБ).

> 1. с использованием QImage:

```
const QString tmb_file = "C:\\Users\\User\\thumbnail.jpg";
const QImage img = QImage(tmb_file, "JPG");
const QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(img);
ui->labelThumb->setPixmap(pixmap);
```

> 2. напрямую через QPixmap:

```
const QString tmb_file = "C:\\Users\\User\\thumbnail.jpg";
const QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap(tmb_file);
ui->labelThumb->setPixmap(pixmap);
```

Comment: ¿что значит "не удается"?

Comment: >>¿что значит "не удается"?
>>

не получается

>> https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F

Comment: фразы типа "не удается" "не получается" "не работает" не являются описанием проблемы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: В QLabel должна выводиться картинка, а она не выводится

Comment: не знаю, как еще объяснить

Comment: Может это изображение вообще не загружается? Или контрол невидимый? Из этих клочков кода совершенно непонятно, с чего вы взяли, что проблема именно в том, что картинка не выводится.

Comment: та же программа прекрасно работает у меня в Linux. Сейчас ребята с форума Qt подсказали, что по какой-то причине у меня в Qt нет поддержки формата JPG. При том, что у меня установлена версия Qt 5.15

Comment: решил вопрос заменой формата jpg на png

Answer (score 1):

png поддерживается на сколько я знаю и без плагинов. для других форматов понадобятся плагины imageformats
не работает ни в отладчике ни при запуске напрямую?

1. проверьте а есть ли что-то типа ...\imageformats\qjpeg.dll (в путях или в каталоге программы. если не уверены, можете сделать windeployqt)
2. И еще можно проверить что на текущий момент поддерживается

   qDebug()<<QImageWriter::supportedImageFormats();

Comment: да, когда Qt не находит imageformats/qjpeg.dll будет пустое место. imageformats должен быть где и exe, но при программировании он обычно находится в библиотеках Qt